# How to Remove Select Option Using jQuery Variable Instead of Hard-Coded Value?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use a variable in a jQuery function rather than using a hard-coded value since the value is not known in advance, as it is based on the current user's login.

The following works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.checkDistrict').change(function(){
var filter= $("#DISTRICTCODE").val();
$("#schools option[data-district-code!='3201']").remove();
});
```

The following does NOT work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.checkDistrict').change(function(){
var filter= $("#DISTRICTCODE").val();
$("#schools option[data-district-code!=" + filter + ]").remove();
});
```

Neither does the following:

```
$('.checkDistrict').change(function(){
var filter= $("#DISTRICTCODE").val();
$('#schools option').each(function() {
if ($(this).attr('data-district-code').indexOf(filter) > -1) {
} else {
$(this).remove();}  
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change this:

> $("#schools option[data-district-code!=" + filter + ]").remove();

To this:

> $("#schools option[data-district-code!='" + filter + "']").remove();

Comment: sorry, netAction, your suggestion did not resolve issue, but thanks anyway. Nijin's suggestion resolved my issue (see below).

Answer (score 0):

```
var filter= $('#DISTRICTCODE').val();
$('#schools > option[data-district-code!=' + filter+ ']').remove();
```

Comment: @whileman happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)